# Expressjs: res.json removes the empty subdocument of mongoose result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My Schema is as follows:

```
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userEmail: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    subscription: {}
});
```

I have a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565c16d3951a55934acaca75"),
    "userEmail" : "abc@example.com",
    "subscription" : {
        "project1" : {
            "subproject1" : [ 
                "comp1"
            ]
        },
        "project2" : {}
    }
}
```

Using mongoose, if I try this:

```
router.post('/getApi', function(req, res, next) {
    MyModel.findOne(
        {
            userEmail: "abc@example.com"
        }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.json(data);
        }
    );
});
```

I'm getting output as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("565c16d3951a55934acaca75"),
    "userEmail" : "abc@example.com",
    "subscription" : {
        "project1" : {
            "subproject1" : [ 
                "comp1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The `project2` is removed since it has empty document. If I try in mongo console, I'm not facing this issue.

I suspect issue in `res.json()` method. Because when `console.log(data)`, I'm getting what I expected. Kindly share your views.

Comment: To be clear, if you replace `res.json()` with `console.log(data)`. the property `project1` is included?

Comment: Yes both 'project1' and 'project2' are included.

Comment: Is `project2` defined in the schema of `MyModel`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Added the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. We have to set `minimize` option to false as part of our `Schema` definition. The documentation says: mongoose [minimize](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#minimize) option. I had it to set it `false`.

So my schema becomes:

```
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userEmail: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    subscription: {}
}, {minimize: false});
```

And this solved my problem.